# How to Run Python on Komodo IDE that read from text file?

Tags: python, komodo

I am using Komodo IDE and have a python file that reads text from a text file, does calculations, then outputs to the console. I am using a command to run the file, with the phrase `%(python3) -u "%F` in the command part.

When I run this file in debugger, it works fine, but when I run it using the command to output to Command Output, this error pops up:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\Saud\A School Work\Z-Computer Programming\ECOO Practice\2010Problem1.py", line 1, in <module>
    f = open('2010DATA.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2010DATA.txt'`

This command runs other programs, just not ones that read from text files.  Here is a picture of the code, command and and error.
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: see the output of `os.getcwd()`. if that is the directory where your file is then it will read.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put `os.getcwd()` in the Start In directory and it worked. May I ask what it actually did?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "Start in" directory to the directory on which you are executing your command, or refrain from using relative paths.